# Typescript extendable generic type/interface

Tags: typescript, generics

so i want to make some kind of base interface/type that can have the properties extended based on the generic object it has.

somekind like this:

```
interface BaseObject<Extension extends object = {}>{
   a: string;
   b: string;
   {...Extension} <<< this is something i know works in object but not here
} 

const sample:BaseObject<{x: number}> = {
    a: '123',
    b: '123',
    x: 123 <<<< forcing type check
}
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by extending the interface itself.

```
interface LessBaseObject extends BaseObject {
  x: number;
}

const sample: LessBaseObject = {
  a: '123',
  b: '123',
  x: 123,
};
```

Comment: i know this way ofc, but i want it to be doable by BaseObject<{x: number}>, this is the essence of the question, i dont want to make a new interface that is only one time use

Comment: What is the advantage to declaring properties in the generic versus declaring the properties as a separate interface?

Comment: i guess that you dont have to declare new interface entirely

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is by mapped types over `Extension`. For whatever reason, TypeScript does not allow you to declare a type that uses mapped types *and* declares property types or use mapped types in an `interace` declaration, but you can create a type that is the intersection of `Extension` and the base properties to achieve this although the syntax is a bit funky:

```
type BaseObject<
  Extension extends object = {},
  All = Extension & { a: string; b: string }
> = {
  [K in keyof All]: All[K];
};
```

Note that using the second generic property is not strictly necessary. You could also write it like this:

```
type BaseObject<Extension extends object = {}> = {
  [K in keyof (Extension & { a: string; b: string })]: (Extension & {
    a: string;
    b: string;
  })[K];
};
```